# regression using two datasets, I am confused

Tags: regression, logistic

I am currently working on a group project about how the proportion of staff who are vaccinated in nursing home affect the flu risk of the elderly who stays in nursing home. It looks simple at first, but we are given two **separate** datasets:

Dataset 1 (Elderly patients)
| ID | Age | Sex|Nursing Home | Flu Status (0/1)|
| -------- | -------------- | --|  --|  --|
| 1| 66| M|  A|  0|
| 2| 79| F|  B|  1|
| 3| 88| M|  C|  1|
| 4| 72| F|  B|  1|
...

Dataset 2 (Nursing Home Staff)
| ID | Age | Sex|Nursing Home | Vaccination(Yes/No)|
| -------- | -------------- | --|  --|  --|
| 1| 35| M|  C|  Yes|
| 2| 43| F|  D|  No|
| 3| 46| M|  A|  No|
| 4| 39| F|  B|  Yes|
...

So far my group agrees on that we use logistic regression with flu status as the response variable for the analysis. But how exact do we account for the proportion of staff who are vaccinated in nursing home when the information is from a separate dataset?

Edit:
Hi Dave Jonathan, thank you for your comments. Just now we did calculate the ”proportion of staff who are vaccinated” by each nursing home from dataset 2, and then merge to dataset 1 to be the following:
| ID | Age | Sex|Nursing Home | Vaccination(Yes/No)|  Vac Proportion|
| -------- | -------------- | --|  --|  --|  --|
| 1| 35| M|  C|  Yes| 80%|
| 2| 43| F|  D|  No|  72%|
| 3| 46| M|  A|  No| 36%|
| 4| 39| F|  B|  Yes| 55%|
| 5| 39| F|  A|  Yes| 36%|
| 6| 39| F|  C|  Yes| 80%|
...

We can see that the proportion of vaccination is a one-to-one function of nursing due to how we calculate it. Does this affect the validity or assumption for logistic regression analysis? I mean, are we on the right track or should we calculate the proportion in other ways?

If you have other suggestion, might you be also willing to share?

Arigatou

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What have you tried or speculated is possible? What issues have you encountered or do you foresee?

Comment: Do you see how you could calculate ”proportion of staff who are vaccinated” from dataset 2?

Comment: Hi Dave and Jonathan. Thank you for your comments. I made the updates in the question. Basically the issue now is that the proportion of staff vaccination by each nursing home is a one-to-one function to nursing home (well, obviously). Does that create any problem for the logistic regression analysis?

Comment: Is there another way to calculate the proportion? By one-to-one, do you mean that all patients in the same nursing home are exposed to the same proportion of staff vaccinated?

Comment: So in both datasets the "nursery home" variable is consistent. To calculate the proportion of staff who are vaccinated in dataset 2, we can do so by each nursery home. For example nursery home A could have 20 staff and 2 are vaccinated, then vaccinated proportion for nursery home A is 0.1. If we do this for other nursery homes with dataset 2 and merge to dataset 1 by nursery home, then as you said all patients in the same nursing home would be exposed to the same proportion of staff vaccinated.